# Geometric distribution/ Formula

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a geometrically distributed random variable $X$.  I want to calculate $P(X \geq k)$.

I get that $P(X \geq k)= (1-p)^{k-1}$.

Now I want to show that $P(X \geq k+n \mid X\geq n) = P(X \geq k)$.

By definition, I get
\begin{align}
P(X \geq k+n \mid X\geq n) &= \frac{P(X \geq k+n)}{P(X \geq k)} \\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{k+n-1}}{(1-p)^{n-1}} \\
&= (1-p)^k \ne  P(X \geq k).
\end{align}

Can somebody tell me, where I've made a mistake?

Comment: Your calculations are correct, and the desired proposition is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then my task must be wrong.

Comment: Can you correct this proposition?

Comment: Are you sure that I am correct?

Comment: Instead of appealing to other people, it's much more important that you convince yourself that you calculations are correct.  You may consider the event of your first probability as the event that the first k-1 trials fail, and reason from the definition of conditional probability.  Then you may convince yourself that your calculations are correct.

Comment: I was viewing on my phone 7 hours ago, and I didn't spot out your typo $$P(X \geq k+n \mid X\geq n) = \frac{P(X \geq k+n)}{P(X \geq \color{red}{n})}.$$  But that *doesn't* affect the rest of your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**geometric distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) has **two** possible senses.

$$\underbrace{\underbrace{\bbox[5px, border: solid 1px]{F} \;\cdots\; \bbox[5px, border: solid 1px]{F}}_{\Large Y \text{ failures}} \quad \bbox[5px, border: solid 1px]{S}}_{\Large X \text{ trials}}$$

1. $X$ meaning the number of *trial(s)* until first success.
2. $Y$ meaning the number of *failure(s)* until first success.  It's clear that $Y = X - 1$.

Since the above *correct* calculations *doesn't* justify the desired claim for $X$, I *guess* that the proposition should hold for $Y$ instead.

Begin with $$P(Y \ge k) = P(X - 1 \ge k) = P(X \ge k + 1) = (1 - p)^k.$$

\begin{align}
P(Y \geq k+n \mid Y\geq n) &= \frac{P(Y \geq k+n)}{P(Y \geq n)} \\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{k+n}}{(1-p)^{n}} \\
&= (1-p)^k =  P(Y \geq k).
\end{align}

Hence, your mistake is the wrong choice of the type of geometric distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome !  Thanks for accept.